# my delete and update buttons not working? below is the MVC

Tags: php, codeigniter

i cant figure out why it is not responding.my code seem right with no errors, or may be there are errors that am not just noticing. thanks in advance.

**controller**

```
function update()

    {

            if($this->input->post('cancel')){
            $this->index();
            }

            elseif($this->input->post('delete')){
            $this->load->model('Attendance_model');
            $data['getData'] = $this->Attendance_model->getdb();
          $this->Attendance_model->deletedb($this->input->post('delete'));
            $this->input->post('DeptCode');
            }

            elseif($this->input->post('update')){
            $this->load->model('Attendance_model');
```

**Model**

```
function updatedb() {

    foreach($EmpNo as $key=>$row) {
    $data = array('EmpNo'=>$row,

        'EmpName'=>$EmpName[$key],

        'Designation'=>$Designation[$key],

        'DayInTime'=>$DayInTime[$key],
        );

    $this->db->where('EmpNo', $key);
    $this->db->update('AttnDetails', $data);
    }
}

function deletedb($deleteId) {
            foreach($deleteId as $key=>$row) {

    $this->db->delete('AttnDetails', array('ID' => $key));
            }
    }
```

Comment: codeigniter framework??

Comment: yes it's codeigniter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function deletedb($deleteId) {
    $count = count($deleteId);

    if (!empty($count) && $count != 1 ) {
        # if array its come here
        foreach($deleteId as $row) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->delete('AttnDetails');//table name
        }
    }
    elseif ($count==1) {
        # if single data its come here...
        $id = $deleteId;
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->delete('AttnDetails');//table name
    }
    else{
        # if empty its come here...
        echo "Array is empty";
    }

}
```

or

```
function deletedb($deleteId) {
    $count = count($deleteId);

    if (!empty($count)) {
        foreach($deleteId as $row) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->delete('AttnDetails');//table name
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "Array is empty";
    }       
}
```

Comment: have done that but it's giving me this error. Illegal string offset 'ID'

Comment: in my code there is no field call `ID`, it should be `id`

Comment: for me i use ID because thats the field.still id brings same error. and  now this...... Message: Array to string conversion.....

Filename: database/DB_query_builder.php

Comment: use second one in below

Comment: yeah it didn't change any

Comment: @flevian ddint get what you say

Comment: @flevian happy to help

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array('EmpNo'=>$row,

        'EmpName'=>$EmpName[$key],

        'Designation'=>$Designation[$key],

        'DayInTime'=>$DayInTime[$key],
        );
```

In you $data, delete the comma 'DayInTime'=>$DayInTime[$key],

Your data and model should be like this ;

```
    function updatedb() {

    foreach($EmpNo as $key=>$row) {
    $data = array('EmpNo'=>$row,

        'EmpName'=>$EmpName[$key],

        'Designation'=>$Designation[$key],

        'DayInTime'=>$DayInTime[$key]
        );

    $this->db->where('EmpNo', $key);
    $this->db->update('AttnDetails', $data);
    }
}

function deletedb($deleteId) {
            foreach($deleteId as $key=>$row) {

    $this->db->delete('AttnDetails', array('ID' => $key));
            }
    }
```